# How can I add a custom button in ckeditor 5, in laravel 10,

Tags: laravel-blade, ckeditor5

this is my code that I use in laravel to work with ckeditor, I want to add custom button , when press on it , insert div in the content,

```
    function setCKEditor(element, name) {
                // Set CKEditor Params
                params = {
                    language: 'ar',
    
                    toolbar: {
                        items: [
                            "sourceEditing",
                            "selectAll",
                            "undo", "redo", '|',
                        ...
                        
                            "tableRow",
                            "mergeTableCells",

                        ],
                        shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
                    },
                    link: {
                        defaultProtocol: 'https://',
                    },
                    mediaEmbed: {
                        previewsInData: true
                    },
                
                }

                // Create CKEditor
                createEditor(element, name, params)
            }
```

```
function createEditor(element, name, params) {
                if (editors[ name ]) return editors[ name ];

                CKEDITOR.ClassicEditor
                    .create(element, params)
                    .then(editor => {
                        removeMediaClass();
                        editor.model.document.on('change', () => removeMediaClass());
                        editors[name] = editor;
                        return editor;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });

            }
```

when click on the button insert div element to content

Comment: do you have a defined plugin? can you share?